# unbelievable issue with ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, arraylist

I just bumpted into serious issue. In my finnaly state of finishing app, when i need to prints all in `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, i got something weird. Look simple:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String> > parentArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String> >();

    System.err.println("emails::::::: parentArray size: " + list.size());

    for ( int parentIndex = 0; parentIndex  < parentArray .size(); parentIndex++){
        ArrayList<String> childArray = parentArray.get(parentIndex);
        for ( int childIndex = 0; childIndex < childArray.size(); childIndex++)
            System.out.println(childArray.get(childIndex));
    }
```

And on output, `just emails::::::: list size: 62`.
Also tried:

- To convert to this:

  String[] databaseOfChild = (String[]) childArray.toArray(new String[childArray.size());

Comment: You may have blank array list in each of the parent list index. Show us the code how you put your elements in the arraylist. And what is `list` in first sop ?

Comment: I can't show code cause, it's too long, and complex.

Comment: print size of `childArray ` inside first for loop to check whether any element exists or not

Comment: you are printing the size of variable `list` not `parentArray`

Comment: yes, that's the issue

Comment: `... parentArray size: " + list.size()` - `parentArray` size certainly isn't `list.size()`. If your example is correct, `parentArray` just got initialized on the first line as empty, and remains empty throughout your example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
System.err.println("emails::::::: parentArray size: " + parentArray.size());
```

to output the size of parentArray - You are printing the size of some other list that is not in your example code.